# Create a view for different attributes from different tables

Tags: view, database-agnostic

I have three tables:

```
product(pid,name,category,maker-cid)
purchase(buyer-ssn,seller-ssn,quantity,pid)
person(ssn,name,phone number,city)
```

How can I create a view to expose only the Buyer name, Seller name and product name from all transactions?

Comment: Are you asking this with regard to a specific database product (if so, which) or are you looking for a universal solution (if so, why)?

Comment: i just had problem dealing with this question as i was learning about the concept of view.so, the universal solution is also accepted.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to join the tables, projecting out the columns you need and wrap that in a view. For example:

```
CREATE VIEW "view name"
AS
SELECT 
    B.Name "Buyer Name",
    S.Name "Seller Name",
    PRD.Name "Product Name"
FROM Purchase PUR
JOIN Person B 
    ON B.ssn = PUR."buyer-ssn"
JOIN Person S 
    ON S.ssn = PUR."seller-ssn"
JOIN Product PRD 
    ON PRD.pid = PUR.pid;
```